# Submit form and return reference number using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have an jQuery AJAX page which submits a form element, paragraph_text:

```
var paragraph_text = $("#paragraph").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
                'paragraph_text': paragraph_text,
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("Data saved");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Data were not saved");
        }
    });
```

And the corresponding insert.php code:

```
$paragraph_text = $_GET['paragraph_text'];

$sql = "query string";

$vote = $dbhandle->query($sql);

$reference = generate_ref();
```

This works fine, but what I want to do is pass $reference back to the original form page asynchronously. Any neat ways to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: `echo $reference; die;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo your data that you get from `$reference`

```
$reference = generate_ref();
echo $reference; exit;
```

Then you can use the response in the success function.

```
var paragraph_text = $("#paragraph").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insert.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
                'paragraph_text': paragraph_text,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            //or do whatever you want with response
            alert("Data saved "+ response);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Data were not saved");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that you have both recommended the use of echo $reference. My question then is: how do I pick-up the value inside the original form page?

Comment: Aren't you getting that with `$paragraph_text = $_GET['paragraph_text'];`? I'm lost by what you mean pickup the value?

Comment: Thanks, it works. I missed one of the changes you made; 'success: function(response)...'